# newbie C pointers question

Tags: c, pointers

```
    #include "stdio.h"

void Square(int num, int *myPointer);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int originalNum = 5;
    Square(originalNum, &originalNum);
    printf("%i\n", originalNum);
    return 0;
}

void Square(int num, int *myPointer) {
    *myPointer = num*num;
}
```

I don't understand how we can pass in &originalNum for a pointer parameter when originalNum is an int. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`originalNum` is an int. `&originalNum` is a pointer to `originalNum` and thus pointer to an int or `int *`.

In simpler words, `&originalNum` is the address where the `originalNum` variable is allocated in the memory. So, when you pass `&originalNum` you don't pass `5` (the value of `originalNum`). Instead, you pass the address where this `5` is stored.

Answer (score 1):

`&` means: "address of". `originalNum` is an int therefore `&originalNum` is an `int*` (a pointer).

Answer (score 0):

`originalNum` is an int, and `&originalNum` is its address. This is of type `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

originalNum is an int,
&originalNum is a pointer over an int
the operator & takes the address of originalNum, so it creates a pointer.